# Which design programs can be used to import and edit data tables?

Tags: data-visualisation, tables

I am currently struggling to find programs that allow me to design data tables.

I started with Adobe XD but none of the plugins for importing data tables worked. I tried other programs like Framer. InDesign was the only program I could find that would import a data table but even then, the data table was finnicky and didn't have the same structure as the original Excel file.

I am looking to design data tables for both web design and print design so any program that allows them to be imported and designed would be a huge help.

Comment: What format are your data tables in? Just Excel files? And what format do you need them in? For web design, you’ll most likely need them converted to HTML tables, but what printing format are you talking about? Should they appear among text in a manual/report/something, and if so, what is being used to typeset the rest of it?

Comment: Some of the data I work with is in Excel and some are in Google Sheets - but I can switch between those easily. Same for web, some is in HTML and others in Java. But converting is not a big deal either because I don't need to have the same exact information in my design at this point. I will literally accept any program that allows me to import any data table for design. Currently, I am creating boxes manually in some programs like Adobe XD but this is just too tedious for long term development.

Comment: For the printed design, I would use InDesign. Place your Excel file (not sure how well Google Sheets would work, never tried), rather than copy-pasting the contents. That should bring in the table reasonably accurately with the original structure, and you can then style it as you wish (though yes, they are a bit finicky in InDesign in general). For web, if you already have them as HTML tables, what more do you need? Styling those tables with CSS _is_ how you’d design them for web use. If you need more specific advice, I think you’ll have to post some examples of your data and desired outcomes.